# How can I set the style of a dojo-element?

Tags: css, dojo, dijit.layout

I'm using an accordion container, like this:

```
<div class="order-accordion" dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer">
    ...
</div>
```

The dojo-framework converts it to the actual accordioncontainer.

```
<div title="" dojotype="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer"
     class="order-accordion dijitContainer dijitAccordionContainer dijitLayoutContainer dijitAccordionContainer-child dijitAccordionContainer-dijitAccordionContainer dijitVisible" id="dijit_layout_AccordionContainer_4" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_layout_AccordionContainer_4"
     style="overflow: hidden; width: 338px; height: 461px;" role="tablist">
    ...
</div>
```

For this element I wanted it to use scrollbars when necessary, which I declared using css for the class `order-accordion`. However, dojo adds a style to the element itself, which overrides my value for overflow.

How do I prevent dojo from adding this style to the element. Or, alternatively, how do I override this value. I've already tried adding a style-attribute to the original `div`, but that is totally ignored/overridden by dojo.

I would prefer a way to provide my own values to the element, instead of using javascript to go over my elements to find all these elements and alter them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.order-accordion { overflow:visible !important; }
```